# Exercise 5 .39 page 46 Real and Abstract Analysis [Hewitt and Stromberg]

Tags: analysis, field-theory, ordered-fields

How to show that every non-Archimedian field contains a subfield algebraically and order isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(t)$, where $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ is the field of rational functions with coefficient in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Your question is not clear: what do you mean by "algebraically and order"?? Also, non-Archimedean field of characteristic $>0$ cannot contain a subfield of characteristic $0$...

Comment: @Ferra Algebraically and order means providing a homomorphism (indeed injective) which preserves the field operations and ordering. Also any finite field can not be ordered but I am asking of ordered field.

Comment: what are your own thoughts on how to construct such a field? Have you thought about what you can do with a nonstandard element of the field?

Comment: @CarlMummert, I do not know What are "nonstandard element" of the field?

Comment: @Steve - I mean an element that is not bounded, within the field, by any element of the subring generated by 1.